# the type in a swift generic function can be decided by the returned value?

Tags: swift, generics

My question comes from this apple tutorial project:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Landmark is a modal struct:

```
struct Landmark: Hashable, Codable , Identifiable{
    ....
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var park: String
    var state: String
    var description: String
    ...
}
```

A list of Landmarks are loaded from a json file.

```
var landmarks: [Landmark] = load("landmarkData.json")
```

The load function is a generic function:

```
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    ...
    file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    ...
}
```

The following is content of file "landmarkData.json":

```
    [
    {
        "name": "Kuring-gai",
        "category": "Forest",
        "city": "Sydney",
        "state": "NSW",
        "id": 1000,
        "isFeatured": true,
        "isFavorite": true,
        "park": "Kuring-gai National Park",
        "coordinates": {
            "longitude": -116.166868,
            "latitude": 34.011286
        },
        "description": "forest.",
    "imageName": "kuringai"
    },
    ...
]
```

The Landmark is not passed to the function "load" as a parameter. How is the type of T is decided? Is the type decided by the returned value, when it is called? Thanks!

Comment: Actually Generic type is decided by Passsing the value type.

Comment: You tell the compiler what's the return value, it's a `[Landmark]`, by writing: `var landmarks: [Landmark]`. It's conform to `Decodable` so, it's "deducing the rest".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Swift type inference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID322) is able to determine what type `load` should return because the type is explicitely stated in the declaration of `landmarks`.

You will get an error if you omit the type :

```
var landmarks = load("landmarkData.json") // Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

but you can also write :

```
var landmarks = load("landmarkData.json") as [Landmark]
```

And if you want to read more on that matter you can check-out this [article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/type-inference/)

Comment: Thanks! That link is what I am looking for.